# Problem with statsmodels ARIMA out-of-sample forecast

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima, forecast

I am developing an ARIMA model to forecast oil exports. Please see the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import stats_can

# Get and preprocess data
df = stats_can.sc.vectors_to_df("v1001826820", periods=200)
df.rename(columns={"v1001826820": "oil_exports"}, inplace=True)
df.index.rename('date', inplace=True)
df["log_oil_exports"] = df.apply(np.log)

# Plot logarithm of oil exports
df.log_oil_exports.plot.line()

# Run ADF test on levels
adfuller(df.log_oil_exports, regression='ct', autolag='AIC')

# Plot first difference of log oil exports
df.log_oil_exports.diff().dropna().plot.line()

# Run ADF test on first difference
adfuller(df.log_oil_exports.diff().dropna(), regression='nc', autolag='AIC')

# Fit ARIMA(1,1,2) model
oil_export_model = ARIMA(endog=df.log_oil_exports, order=(1, 1, 2), trend='t')
oil_export_model_fit = oil_export_model.fit()
oil_export_model_fit.summary()

# Print last 5 observations from the training data
df.log_oil_exports.tail()

# Print last 5 fitted values
oil_export_model_fit.predict()[-5:]

# Make an out-of-sample forecast
oil_export_model_fit.forecast()
```

The last five observations from the training dataset are:

```
2021-04-01    8.902456
2021-05-01    8.896834
2021-06-01    9.132130
2021-07-01    9.101674
2021-08-01    9.182167
Name: log_oil_exports, dtype: float64
```

The last 5 fitted values are:

```
2021-04-01    8.957241
2021-05-01    8.890469
2021-06-01    8.925859
2021-07-01    9.113322
2021-08-01    9.098928
Freq: MS, dtype: float64
```

The first out-of-sample prediction is

```
2021-09-01    7.708736
Freq: MS, dtype: float64
```

To say the truth, I cannot understand how the first out-of-sample prediction is 7.7087 when the preceding five observed and fitted values are all close to 9. Am I missing something obvious here? I would appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried other ARIMA orders or tried Seasonal ARIMA (SARIMAX)?

Comment: @ArneDecker, the problem seems to be caused by setting trend="t". When I fit the model without a trend, forecasts seem to be in line with expectations.